# jquery color wheel drive background of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the color wheel from 'jquerycolorwheel' change the background color of a container div which contains a png (which has transparency in it to reveal the background color behind it).

https://pallighting.com.au/shop/evenglow-pool-light/

As I have it, the preview box from jquery is just positioned behind the image to give the effect I'm after. It works but at different screen sizes it's becoming a nightmare to keep the box correctly positioned. So making the container div have the right background color would be a better solution.

I've tried adding lines of code to the jquery.wheelcolorpicker.js file to make that change the div's background color and also tried setting up a jquery script that listens for changes to the fill color of the preview box and applies that to the background of the image. Both seem like suitable solutions but I haven't been able to get them to work. Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Code from jquery color wheel that I believe is adding color to it's preview box:

```
     /// PREVIEW ///
// Preview box must always be redrawn, if not hidden
var $previewBox = $widget.find('.jQWCP-wPreviewBox');
if(!$previewBox.hasClass('hidden')) {
  var previewBoxCtx = $previewBox.get(0).getContext('2d');
  previewBoxCtx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + R + "," + G + "," + B + "," + A + ")";
  previewBoxCtx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
  previewBoxCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
}
```

I've tried adding this code to that, declaring the variable under the $previewBox variable and the .css attribute until the .fillRect function:

```
 var $bgImg = $widget.find('.colorwheelimg');


      bgImg.css( "background-color", "rgba(" + R + "," + G + "," + B + "," + A + ");
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I've got a work around, I'm adding the image as a background image on the parent container for the preview box and putting the preview box then behind it with z-index... seems to work...